# Прототипное наследование || JavaScript

Tags: javascript, наследование, прототипное-наследование

Для закрепления данной темы решил посмотреть гайды/почитать статейки и написать код

```
function Animal(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

function Rabbit(name, age, color) {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments);
  this.color = color;
}

Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;

let rabbit = new Rabbit('Rabbit', 4, 'White');
```

Вопрос конкретно по данной строке:

```
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;
```

Я понимаю, что при наследовании у Rabbit будет конструктор, как у Animal, но не до конца понятно, какие проблемы могут быть вызваны отсутствием данной строки кода.

Comment: если ты не будешь использовать это поле - то никаких

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor - Оно заметно в очень специфичных случаях. Поэтому существует синтаксис class-ов, чтобы не париться за такое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не наследовать то
прототип по умолчанию

```
Rabbit.prototype = { constructor: Rabbit }
```

Но так как вы переопределяете прототип в предыдущей строке, то логично вернуть конструктор обратно на место